# Checkbox selectAll\DeselectAll in tableLayout

Tags: android

I have List of route in tablelayout.
CheckBox & TextView created dynamically.
I set the checkbox id.

I want to do the selectall & deselectAll . How we can implement?

I created checkBox using coding.then How can call this `CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.????);`

```
 tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.dailyDRoute);
    ArrayList<SalesRoutes> routeList = getSalesRoute();
    for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
        ch.setHeight(1);
        ch.setId(i);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tr.addView(ch);
        tv2.setText(routeList.get(i).getDescription());
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        tr.addView(tv2); 
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
}


 public void deselectAll(View view){
    // CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.);

 }


 public void selectAll(View view){

 }
```

[image]

Please help me ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R.id.* are integer constants generated during build process. Actually, you need to pass an integer id to `findViewById` (same integer as you set us as id in init block).
Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount(); i++) {
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(i);
  cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

But as for me this is not very reliable because id set in runtime can be not unique and I think this loop is better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tl.getChildCount(); i++) {
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)((TableRow)tl.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0);
  cb.setChecked(true);
}
```